# React PWA offline fallback page with workbox

Tags: reactjs, next.js, web-applications, progressive-web-apps, workbox

I have react app and I am trying to implement offline fallback page to be shown to the user whenever navigate from one route to another while he is offline. I followed workbox official site to do it. Now when the user open my app then switch off the internet connection and try to navigate to another route let's say he was in home route `/` and navigated to `/posts` route the offline.html page is not showing to the user unless he reload the page. so my question is that is there anyway to make the offline page or route shown to the user without reloading the page.

here is my sw.js

```
/* eslint-disable no-restricted-globals */


import { precacheAndRoute } from 'workbox-precaching';

import { offlineFallback } from 'workbox-recipes';
import { setDefaultHandler } from 'workbox-routing';
import { NetworkOnly } from 'workbox-strategies';

setDefaultHandler(new NetworkOnly());

offlineFallback();

precacheAndRoute(self.__WB_MANIFEST);
self.skipWaiting();
```